# SAP Crystal Report SetDataSource function throwing "An unhandled exception"

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, datasource

I have trouble in VS 2013 SAP Crystal Reports using c# to make a WPF application. I get the following error with the following code:

```
CrpInvoice crInv = new CrpInvoice();

crInv.SetDataSource(_lstInvoice); //throwing error here
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Report was developed using an earlier version of the .NET Framework, you need to add these lines to your app.config file:

```
<startup  useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">   
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```